# Facebook Photo Upload Issue

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to do Upload the Photo on Facebook from my Android Device but the following error is occured.

[image]

following is my code for upload photo:-

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("photos.upload", encodedImage);

//post on user's wall.
facebook.dialog(this, "photos.upload", params, new DialogListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Error facebook is:- " + e.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Error Dialog is:- " + e.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Values is:- " + values);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("On Cancel Clicked...");
    }
});
```

so, What is the Problem in above code?
Please Help Me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use facebook AsyncRunner class to upload the photo. It will solve your problem. Try POST in place of photos.upload in facebook.dialog method, I may be wrong but try it once.

Comment: I used this Class but the problem is the photo is not upload.

Comment: Hello Rocker, Your Answer is Working but Problem is Photo is Uploaded Directly to the Album not my wall.

Comment: Ya it will be uploaded to the application album and for the wall I also need to study for that. Let me check how it is done.